# javax Request object not evaluating precondition for If-None-Match header

Tags: rest, webserver, etag, javax, if-none-match

I am running a REST service in Wildfly and I am attempting to use the `Request.evaluatePreconditions` method to generate a `304 Not Modified` response.

I am passing an eTag value in the request's `If-None-Match` header, but the `evaluatePreconditions` method is not generating the `304` response even when the EntityTag matches the value in the `If-None-Match` header.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.EntityTag
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.mycompany.DataClient;
import com.mycompany.ResponseData;

@Path ("entities")
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement (TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class RESTService
{
    @Inject
    private DataClient m_DataClient;

    @GET
    @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response findAllEntities (@Context Request request)
    {
        Response.ResponseBuilder response = null;

        try
        {
            ResponseData responseData = m_DataClient.findAll ();

            EntityTag tag = new EntityTag (responseData.getETag ());

            response = request.evaluatePreconditions (tag);

            if (response == null)
            {
                response = Response.status (responseData.getStatusCode ()).entity (responseData.getEntities ()).tag (responseData.getETag ());
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException | PersistenceException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex)
        {
            m_Logger.log (Level.SEVERE, "Find All Data Exception", ex);
            response = Response.serverError ();
        }

        return response.build ();
    }
}
```

- `ResponseData.getStatusCode ()` returns an `int` that corresponds to an HTTP status code.
- `ResponseData.getEntities ()` returns a `List` of serializable objects.
- `ResponseData.getETag ()` returns a `String` that contains a hash that corresponds to the entity objects returned by `getEntities`.

Here's my request to the server:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -H "If-None-Match:7056166173985" -H "Authorization:Bearer adsf" -k -v https://mycompany.com/entities
```

Here's the response header from the server:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< ETag: "7056166173985"
< X-Powered-By: caffeine
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 1227
< Date: Fri, 27 Oct 2017 02:00:39 GMT
< Via: 1.1 google
< Alt-Svc: clear
<
```

As you can see, the ETag value in the response header matches the value in the `If-None-Match` request header. Why am I not receiving a `304 Not Modified` response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem was in another part of my code that loads the eTag value into the `responseData` object. As a result, the `responseData.getETag ()` method was returning a string that included the opening and closing double quotes. I was able to get things to work by changing

```
EntityTag tag = new EntityTag (responseData.getETag ());
```

to

```
EntityTag tag = new EntityTag (responseData.getETag ().replaceAll ("^\"|\"$", ""));
```

Specifically, I am pulling my data and the associated eTag from a remote server, and I am using the [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to retrieve them.
The following code retrieves the eTag from the header:

```
private String retrieveETag (HttpResponse response)
{
    Header eTagHeader = response.getLastHeader ("etag");

    if (eTagHeader != null)
    {
        return eTagHeader.getValue ();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The raw eTag header is `ETag: \"etagvalue\"`.
I had expected `eTagHeader.getValue ()` to return `etagvalue`, but instead it returns `\"etagvalue\"`.